# Creating a helper instead of placing code in view

Tags: ruby, view-helpers

I have a form where a user can select a dropdown making it more user friendly. The Letters 'C','W', and 'R' are displayed as cycle, walk, & run
The code is below:

```
= f.select :kind, [['cycle','C'],['walk','W'],['run','R']]
```

How would I replace the code above and create a helper to do the same job

maggs

Comment: And why would you like to do this? Is this code somehow common in your views?

Comment: the code is common in the views

Answer (score 0):

I see no benefit in having a helper that does not have more logic than the used `select` already handles. But I would move the nested array to the model that has this options. Than you have a reference in your model about valid options.

Assuming the model is named `Exercise`:

```
# in model
class Exercise
  KINDS = [['cycle','C'],['walk','W'],['run','R']]
  validate :kind, :inclusion => { :in => KINDS }

# in view
= f.select :kind, Exercise::KINDS
```